# At what point should MLSetMessageHandler() be called?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, interruption

I have an `Install`able MathLink program written in C.  I would like to use a custom message handler.  At which point in the C source code should I call `MLSetMessageHandler()`?

The standard structure for such an installable MathLink program is this:

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return MLMain(argc, argv);
}
```

First I tried something like this:

```c
/* does this look OK? */
void msghandler(MLINK link, int msg, int arg) {
    switch (msg) {
    case MLInterruptMessage:
    case MLAbortMessage:
        myabort();
        break;
    default:
        stdhandler(link, msg, arg);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MLSetMessageHandler(stdlink, (MLMessageHandlerObject) msghandler); /* <- wrong place to set it */
    return MLMain(argc, argv);
}
```

(I'm showing this code in full to also get some feedback on the structure of the message handler function.)

This doesn't work for two reasons:

1. `MLSetMessageHandler()` fails and returns the code `MLEDEAD`, which I assume means that the link is not yet initialized.   I suppose that's done in `MLMain()`.
2. `MLMain()` itself will call `MLSetMessageHandler()` and overwrite any previous one.

**Question:** Is there a simpler way to fix this than writing my own `MLMain` replacement (`MLMain` is generated by `mprep`)?

Comment: Why can't you have a custom function to set your message handler and call it as a part of installing your function, after `MlMain` does this?

Comment: You could also use a hack and define a `MLSetMessageHandler` macro using the C preprocessor, to effectively disable the code generated by `mprep`. Something like `#define MLSetMessageHandler(x,y)` and then `#define MLSetMessageHandler(x,y,flag) MLSetMessageHandler(x,y) `. The point is that you will use the second version with a (spurios) flag  - say 0, and since the macro expansion is not recursive, the first version won't be used on the expanded result.

Comment: Actually, the most economical way would be to define the macro as `#define MLSetMessageHandler(link, handler) MLSetMessageHandler(link, (MLMessageHandlerObject) msghandler)`, and then you don't need to set it yourself - as long as this `#define` is included when you compile your files, it will automatically replace the call to `MLSetMessageHandler` that is present in generated `MLMain()`. This should answer both of your concerns at the same time.

Comment: The standard way to define a message handler function is with the MLMDEFN macro, and I recommend that you use it: `MLMDEFN(void, msghandler, (MLINK mlp, unsigned long message, unsigned long n)) { ... }`. Note that the two parameters are longs.

Comment: @ToddGayley and Leonid: Thanks!  Otherwise does the handler look fine, calling `stdhandler` for everything except Interrupt and Abort?  It was not clear to me *which* messages *must* be handled, and how.

Comment: What I ended up with eventually was defining a function callable from Mathematica that set up the handler.  I think I could also move calling this function into the template file.

Comment: @Szabolcs That was my very first suggestion (function callable from M). I did not know about MLMDEFN macro, but apparently was thinking in the right direction :)

Comment: Whether your handler function is right depends on what the `myabort()` function does. The default `stdhandler` simply sets the values of the globals `MLAbort` and `MLDone`, which are examined by the mprep-created code at the end of each call into your program. If `MLAbort` is 1, then the mprep code sends back `Abort[]` instead of the result of your function. Therefore, your `myabort()` function should set `MLAbort = 1`. If your function is a Manual return type, then things are different, and you are sending back the `Abort[]` yourself, so there is no need to manage the value of `MLAbort`.

Comment: @ToddGayley I got the `msghandler` prototype from [this documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/c/MLSetMessageHandler.html).  It uses `int` types.  I checked `mathlink.h` as well, and if I followed the definitions back correctly (it's easy to make a mistake with all the `#ifdef`s) then `MessageHandlerObject` is a `MLHandlerUPP` which is a `MLHandlerProcPtr` which is defined as `MLMPROC( void, MLHandlerProcPtr, (MLINK mlp, int m, int n));`.  Are you sure that the arguments should be `unsigned long`?

Comment: @ToddGayley I was not aware that I need to send `Abort[]` explicitly when the return type is `Manual`, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @ToddGayley I noticed now that the output of mprep has `MLMDEFN( void, MLDefaultHandler, ( MLINK mlp, int message, int n))` if `MLINTERFACE >= 3`, which seems to be the default for Mathematica 9.  It has `unsigned long` otherwise.

Comment: @Szabolcs Well, that's what I get for looking at an old .tm.c file instead of a newer one. You are correct, the current prototype has ints for those arguments.